# How to replace Array to plist in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, replace, plist

my Data in plist is

```
ArrayKey

 item0 100
 item1 200
 item2 300
```

My Function is

```
- (IBAction)Save:(id)sender 
{   
    NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] 
                                       initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    NSMutableArray * array = (NSMutableArray *)[dictionary valueForKey:@"ArrayKey"];
    [array replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:textView1.text];
    [array replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:textView2.text];
    [array replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:textView3.text];
    NSLog(@"Array is :%@",dictionary);
    [dictionary writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}
```

Where is wrong. Help please!

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files in your bundle are read only. If you need to write a file, you need to do that elsewhere in the application's sandbox. (in the user's documents directory or your app's /Library or the cache or tmp directories, depending on what this data actually is)